# I cannot import igraph on python 2.6 after installation

Tags: python, igraph

I installed igraph for python 2.6 on OSX 10.7, but I cannot import igraph library.

It shows a import error:no module name igraph.

I have no idea. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you install igraph for python 2.6? How are you running python 2.6? Are you using the built-in OS X python 2.6, or do you have one or more additional installations of it? Ideally, give the full command lines and output for each step.

Comment: PS, I just grabbed the "OS X Lion Installer (Python 2.6)" from http://igraph.sourceforge.net/download.html, ran the installer with default settings, ran python2.6 in Terminal, and typed "import igraph" and everything worked fine. It's installed in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/igraph/.

Comment: @abamert I installed igraph for python 2.6 with the dmg file provided the website as you know. I reinstalled python 2.6 with the pkg of python.org. The installation of igraph was successful, but I could not import the library as following. >>> import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named igraph

Comment: @abarnert I typed 'igraph' on terminal, and it was possible to import. However, I cannot run code with python. I make a code, and tried to run, such as, 'python ex.py'. It shows the same import error. Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I cannot run code with python. I make a code, and tried to run, such as, 'python ex.py'

OK, even though you didn't answer most of my questions, I'm pretty sure I can guess your problem. Your question title is "I cannot import igraph on python 2.6 after installation", but you're not trying to import it on python 2.6, you're trying on 2.7.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named igraph
>>>

$ python2.6
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import igraph
>>>
```

See the difference? OS X 10.7 (and 10.8) comes with three versions of Python: 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7. They're entirely independent installations, so when you installed igraph for Python 2.6, that didn't install it for your 2.5 or 2.7 installations.

The default, the one you get when you just run `python`, is 2.7. If you want a specific version, you have to run `python2.6` instead.

So, you either need to run python2.6, or install igraph for 2.7.

As a side note, if you've installed any third-party Python installations, you're going to get yourself even more confused, so please, don't do that (or uninstall if you already have) until you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, I have one more question about python version. As you know, there are many versions, such as 2.6.1, 2.6.2, .... I know how to change the default python for OSX, but I have no idea how to change the default python version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I know how to change the default python for OSX, but I have no idea how to change the default python version." What's the distinction you're trying to make? At any rate, unless you have a good reason, you shouldn't be installing any other Python 2.6.x; just use the one that comes with OS X. If you do install a custom 2.6.2, you probably don't want to make that your default `python2.6`, and you almost definitely don't want to make any 2.6 your default `python`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment so far. While I use a python which was already installed on my machine, there is an error message such as, 'it is for python 2.6.2' something like that. I've checked out what I have, and they are different, for instance, 2.6.2 and 2.6.1. That's why I ask.

Comment: Well, the site claims that the packages are designed for the built-in versions of 2.6 and 2.7 on OS X Lion. So if they don't work with the built-in version of 2.6, you should file a bug. And if you need to work around it for now, I think you'd be better off installing from source than trying to hack up your system to match their incorrect binary. If you have Homebrew, it should be as simple as `brew install igraph; sudo pip-2.6 install igraph`. Meanwhile, is there a reason you're using 2.6 instead of 2.7 in the first place?

Comment: Oh, I see. I've installed 2.7, and it works. However, there is another error that needs pycairo. OTL...

Comment: From the website: "Graph plotting functionality is provided by the Cairo library, so make sure you install the Python bindings of Cairo if you want to generate publication-quality graph plots." So, yeah, install Cairo and pycairo.

Comment: Thank you for your all comments.